# How to change the Scale of Y-Axis in R

Tags: r, plot

I have this graph which I'm plotting

[image]

As you can see, the values on the black line which I'm trying to plot is not on the same scale as that of the red line.
Therefore, I'm trying to change the scale of the Y-Axis, so I can essentially "Zoom Out". How do I do this?

What I did till now is:

```
plot(d,vol1, type="l",xaxt="n", xlab="Date", ylab="Volatility Estimate", main="Nasdaq Pharmaceutical Index")

months= seq(min(d), max(d), "month")

axis(1, months, format(months, "%Y\n%b"))

lines(d, vol1, col="black")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the argument `ylim=c(a,b)` inside the `plot()` command, where `a` is the minimum and `b` is the maximum of your desired y-axis.